# Move the Edit button of a User Control to another td using CSS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have a user control designed using a `<table>` for this UI.
[image]

Now I want to move the Edit button from User Control to the same line as dropdown like as shown below.

[image]

Is it possible to move/reposition like this using CSS or should we need to edit the design of User control for this simple thing. I really don't want to edit the design of user control but not sure if its possible with only CSS. Kindly share your expert opinions.
Here is my User Control markup

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" ID="reqLabel" EnableTheming="false"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="domainameLabel" runat="server" Text="" Width="130"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DomainValueDropDownList" runat="server" onchange="OnDomainValueChange(this)"
                    AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DomainValueDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="200px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
             <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNewMessage" Text="New value. Please approve." EnableTheming="false" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Input is required."
                ControlToValidate="DomainValueDropDownList" ForeColor="Red">!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div id="NewDomainValueDiv" runat="server" visible="false">
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="newDomainValueTextBox" runat="server" ToolTip="Click the Add button to add this new value"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" CausesValidation="False" ToolTip="Click button to add this new value" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click"
                        CausesValidation="False" />
                    <asp:Label ID="infoLbl" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="**New Project will be added to selected Platform. Please select the appropriate platform**" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div id="UpdateDomainValueDiv" runat="server">
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
                </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ContentTemplate>
```

My Part of Rendered HTML Page

```
<table>
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>
                <span id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_reqLabel" style="color:Red;">*</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_domainameLabel" style="display:inline-block;color:Black;font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;font-weight:normal;width:130px;">Project Name</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel2$GeneralInformationControl$Project_Name$DomainValueDropDownList" onchange="OnDomainValueChange(this);setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel2$GeneralInformationControl$Project_Name$DomainValueDropDownList\',\'\')', 0)" id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_DomainValueDropDownList" class="dropdownlist" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;font-weight:normal;width:200px;">
                                        <option value=""></option>

                                    </select>
            </td>
            <td>

                <span id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_RequiredFieldValidator1" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">!</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel2$GeneralInformationControl$Project_Name$btnEdit" value="Edit" id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_btnEdit" class="ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only">
                </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

And my CSS Styles from Developer Tools

```
    table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}
Inherited from 
user agent stylesheettable {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}
Inherited from 
Style Attribute {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 9pt;
    width: 100%;
}
Inherited from 
Style Attribute {
    visibility: visible;
}
Inherited from 
.ajax__tab_xp .ajax__tab_body {
    font-family: verdana,tahoma,helvetica;
    font-size: 10pt;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    border-top: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
Inherited from 
Style Attribute {
    visibility: visible;
}
Inherited from 
Style Attribute {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 9pt;
    width: 100%;
}
Inherited from 
body {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #696969;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0fswopb6/)

Comment: How can we help you if you don't show us your code? :)

Comment: You need CSS or User COntrol Code or the Rendered HTML Page?

Comment: Everything that can reproduce this issue.

Comment: Code is ok. Can you create a demo of the output using SO snippet or jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Yup...I'll do it asap

Comment: Pleae find a JSFiddle for this. http://jsfiddle.net/0fswopb6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS solution**

Change `tr` display value to `inline-block`(Works on all browsers, inline is an exception). Default is `table-row` which makes each row take 100% width.

*This is a pure hack and should not be practiced for anything larger than this form.* To not effect other table rows, give a class to this table and target with `.class-name tr`

```css
table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  border-color: grey;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  border-color: grey;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 9pt;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
  font-family: verdana, tahoma, helvetica;
  font-size: 10pt;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border-top: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  visibility: visible;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 9pt;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: .80em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #696969;
}
tr {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <span id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_reqLabel" style="color:Red;">*</span>

      </td>
      <td> <span id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_domainameLabel" style="display:inline-block;color:Black;font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;font-weight:normal;width:130px;">Project Name</span>

      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel2$GeneralInformationControl$Project_Name$DomainValueDropDownList" onchange="OnDomainValueChange(this);setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel2$GeneralInformationControl$Project_Name$DomainValueDropDownList\',\'\')', 0)"
        id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_DomainValueDropDownList" class="dropdownlist" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;font-weight:normal;width:200px;">
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td> <span id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_RequiredFieldValidator1" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">!</span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel2$GeneralInformationControl$Project_Name$btnEdit" value="Edit" id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_btnEdit" class="ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**HTML solution**

This is the standard solution of restructuring the markup. Move the `td` block inside the first `tr`.

```css
table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  border-color: grey;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  border-color: grey;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 9pt;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
  font-family: verdana, tahoma, helvetica;
  font-size: 10pt;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border-top: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  visibility: visible;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 9pt;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: .80em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #696969;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <span id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_reqLabel" style="color:Red;">*</span>

      </td>
      <td> <span id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_domainameLabel" style="display:inline-block;color:Black;font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;font-weight:normal;width:130px;">Project Name</span>

      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel2$GeneralInformationControl$Project_Name$DomainValueDropDownList" onchange="OnDomainValueChange(this);setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel2$GeneralInformationControl$Project_Name$DomainValueDropDownList\',\'\')', 0)"
        id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_DomainValueDropDownList" class="dropdownlist" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;font-weight:normal;width:200px;">
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td> <span id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_RequiredFieldValidator1" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">!</span>

      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel2$GeneralInformationControl$Project_Name$btnEdit" value="Edit" id="MainContent_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GeneralInformationControl_Project_Name_btnEdit" class="ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Moving the `<td>` block into the first `<tr>` needs a change in the UI of the User Control as it renders the HTML. The CSS Solution doesn't put the Edit button on inline with dropdown. Did I miss anything in understanding it. pls lemme know and clarify.

Comment: Is the snippet working and putting the `Edit` button inline with the drop down? If yes, then problem is elsewhere, maybe overriding of CSS.

Comment: The snippet for CSS solution didn't put dropdown inline with edit button..I just tried copy pasting your solution to jsfiddle but didn't look into detail of it. I'll have a more detailed look soon but copy pasting htmll and css onto jsfiddle don't solve the problem. Did I miss something?kindly validate

Comment: You are right. I was working on Firefox. Chrome seems to not effect the element with inline. I tried `inline-block` and it works fine in all browsers.